# Isomorphism $SU(2)/{\pm 1} \leftrightarrow SO(3)$

Tags: lie-groups, group-isomorphism

I have a question regarding the isomorphism from $SU(2)/{\pm 1 \rightarrow SO(3)}$. We defined it to be $\widehat{\Phi(A)x}=A\hat{x}A^{*}$, where $\hat{x}=\sum_{j=1}^3 x_j \sigma_j, x \in \mathbb{R}$ the $\sigma_j$ are the Pauli matrices. My problem is that I don’t see why this is in $SO(3)$. Aren’t $A$ and $x$ 2-dimensional?

Comment: There is `\widehat`: `\widehat{abcde}` gives $\widehat{abcde}$

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a vector $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$. From that you build the $2\times 2$ complex matrix $\widehat{x}$, and then you compute another $2\times 2$ complex matrix $\widehat{y}=A\widehat{x} A^*$, which turns out to be of the form $\sum_{j=1}^3 y_j \sigma_j$ for some vector $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)\in \mathbf{R}^3$. That map from $x$ to $y$ (which you have denoted $\Phi(A)$) is in $SO(3)$.

Comment: Can we write this also in a 3x3 matrix form, where the properties of SO(3) can be checked explicitly?

Comment: Yes, of course. Just take $x=(1,0,0)$, do the computation, and see what vector $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ that you get. This will be the first column in the $3\times 3$ matrix. To get the second and third column, repeat with $x=(0,1,0)$ and $x=(0,0,1)$.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Thanks a lot! I have been somewhat confused by the notation...

Comment: You're welcome!